# How to set attribute value with "&" char

Tags: python, xml, minidom

How to add `"&"` char into XML attribute node? I'm using `xml.dom.minidom`

I'm trying to build XML in Python and original text which I want to set as an attribute contains `'\n'`. I need to replace it with string contains `"&"`

```
basic_string = "#TRANS#\nSTANDARD"
modify = basic_string.replace('\n', '&#xD;&#xA;')
```

When I print out `modify` the result is `"#TRANS#&#xD;&#xA;STANDARD"` but when I set `modify` as an attribute value by `setAttribute` from `minidom`, in XML I've got `"#TRANS#&amp;#xD;&amp;#xA;STANDARD"`. (`&amp` appear instead `&`)

Answer (score 0):

`&` is a special character in XML, it starts an entity. To include the literal `&`, you can use `&amp;` or `&#x26;` or `&#38;`. They are all equivalent, so also freely interchangeable.

Comment: #TRANS#&amp;#38#xD;&amp;#38#xA;STANDARD is a result in XML after replacing

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: exactly: "#TRANS#&#xD;&#xA;STANDARD"

Comment: `&#xD;&#xA;` in XML is the same as `&#13;&#10;` or `&#x0D;` + a newline.